# How to listen to each user individually. Telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота. При запуске он начинает прослушивать входящие сообщения и отвечать на них. Он хорошо работает с одним пользователем. Но когда появляется больше пользователей и они одновременно начинают писать боту, все начинает путаться. Подскажите, как слушать каждого пользователя в отдельности и решить эту проблему. Что использовать?

```
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);

  try {

      if (msg.text.startsWith('/start')) {
        await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "message");
        await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "message", letCheck)
      } 
      
      else if (msg.text.includes('message')) {
        await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "message")


        
        const profileForm = new ProfileForm(bot, msg.chat.id);
        profileForm.filter('phoneNumber', async (value) => {
          const profileExists = await Phones.findOne({where: {phoneNumber: value}});
          if (profileExists) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        });
        const profileData = await profileForm.listen();
          if (!profileData) {
            return;
          }

        console.log(profileData); 
        const user = await User.create(profileData);
        console.log(user);



        await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "message");
        await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "message", onstart)
      }        
     
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }

  })
```

profile

```
const options = require('../../Middleware/options')
class ProfileForm {
  constructor(bot, chatId) {
    this.bot = bot
    this.chatId = chatId
    this.filters = {};
  }

  filter(field, fn) {
    if (!this.filters[field]) {
      this.filters[field] = [];
    }
    this.filters[field].push(fn);
  }

  async checkFilter(field, value) {
    if (!this.filters[field]) {
      return false;
    }

    for (const fn of this.filters[field]) {
      try {
        const result = await fn(value);
        if (!result) {
          throw(`Filter blocked for field: ${field}  with value: ${value}`);
        }
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  async listen() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const fields = [
        {
          name: 'username',
          message: `message` 
        },
        {
          name: 'lastname',
          message: `message`
        }
      ]
      const data = {}
      
      let step = 0
      let allow = false;

      await this.sendMessage(fields[step].message, fields[step].options);

      const profileFormHandler = async (msg) => {
        let {text} = msg
        text = text.trim();
        data[fields[step].name] = text
        
        allow = await this.checkFilter(fields[step].name, text);  
        if (allow) {
          this.bot.off('message', profileFormHandler);
          if (fields[step].stopMessage) {
            await this.sendMessage(fields[step].stopMessage);
          }
          return resolve(null);
        } 

        step++
        if (step === fields.length) {
          this.bot.off('message', profileFormHandler);
          return resolve(data);
        }

        await this.sendMessage(fields[step].message, fields[step].options);
      }

      this.bot.on('message', profileFormHandler);
    })
  }

  async sendMessage(message, options) {
    return this.bot.sendMessage(this.chatId, message, options);
  }
}

module.exports = ProfileForm;
```

Comment: Вангую глобальные переменные/глобальное состояние, но без кода этот вопрос бесполезен

Comment: @AlexeyTen - я добавил код